# I am trying to test smart contracts using forge but I get an error Revert Counterexample

Tags: solidity, forge

my contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;


interface simpleToken {
 function destroy(address _addr) external ;
}


contract Recovery {
  
  simpleToken public token;


  constructor() public payable {
    token = simpleToken(0x35CEA6A258535bF93b54cc8aA37177Ba82857697);
  }


  function destroy(address _to) public  {
   
     token.destroy(_to);
  }
}
```

my test contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "../src/Counter.sol";

contract CounterTest is Test {
    Recovery public recover;

    function setUp() public {
        recover = new Recovery();
    }

    function test_destroy(address _to) public {
        recover.destroy(_to);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the full error message?

Comment: Did you solved this?